# How to handle exceptions in lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, option-type

I have metohod MyService#create which throws CustomException. I call this method in Optional#map like below:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(obj)
        .map(optObj -> {
            try {
                return myService.create(optObj);
            } catch (CustomException e) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        })
        .map(created -> new ResponseEntity<>("Operation successful", HttpStatus.CREATED))
        .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>("Operation failed", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
```

And when I call this method with arguments which cause exception then CustomException is catched but in result I get Operation successful and status 200. How to handle this exception in lambda and return message from exception?

Comment: No, there is throwing exception in lambda. I want to catch and return right result

Comment: What is the reason behind using `Optional` at all? A simple `if - then - else` is enough here, maybe in companion with a `try - catch`.

Comment: try using wrapper method that will be responsible for handling the exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do catch exception and return `new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)`.

Then you map it to `new ResponseEntity<>("Operation successful", HttpStatus.CREATED)`.

If you want to have `new ResponseEntity<>("Operation successful", HttpStatus.CREATED)` only if call is successful rewrite your code to:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(obj)
        .map(optObj -> {
            try {
                myService.create(optObj);
                return new ResponseEntity<>("Operation successful", HttpStatus.CREATED);
            } catch (CustomException e) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        })
        .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>("Operation failed", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
```